# Row filtering to an af:table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

I am trying to enable filtering in af:table but it does not return any result.

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.PaisUVO.collectionModel}" var="row"
              rows="#{bindings.PaisUVO.rangeSize}"
              emptyText="#{bindings.PaisUVO.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
              fetchSize="#{bindings.PaisUVO.rangeSize}"
              rowBandingInterval="0" styleClass="AFStretchWidth"
              selectionListener="#{bindings.PaisUVO.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
              rowSelection="single" id="t1" binding="#{pageFlowScope.paisMB.tableData}"
              scrollPolicy="page" autoHeightRows="0"
              filterModel="#{bindings.PaisUVOQuery.queryDescriptor}"
              queryListener="#{bindings.PaisUVOQuery.processQuery}"  filterVisible="true">
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.PaisUVO.hints.NewsiteOxiPaisesNome.name}"
                    sortable="false"
                    headerText="#{bundle['lbl_pais']}"
                    id="c7" filterable="true">
            <af:outputText value="#{row.NewsiteOxiPaisesNome}" id="ot2"/>
                <f:facet name="filter"/>
            </af:column>
```

Also set the searchRgion in pageDef.xml properly

```
<executables>
<iterator Binds="PaisUVO" RangeSize="5" DataControl="OxitenoAMDataControl"
          id="PaisUVOIterator" Sortable="true">
  <sortCriteria>
    <sort attribute="NewsiteOxiPaisesPk" ascending="false"/>
  </sortCriteria>
</iterator>
<searchRegion Binds="PaisUVOIterator" Criteria=""
              Customizer="oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUSearchBindingCustomizer"
              id="PaisUVOQuery"/>
```

Also followed this link: [Row filtering](https://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/how-to-add-row-filtering-to-aftable.html).

I am using jdev 11.1.1.7.0. Can anyone point out what can cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering should work by default if you just check the check box for that behavior when you add the table to the page.
See this image:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/ps1/ria_application/images/t059_Alt.gif
From this tutorial - http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/ps1/ria_application/developriaapplication_long.htm

Create a page this way - and then compare it to the page you are trying to modify manually.

Comment: It actually works by default but only when i change my taskflow and than access it again. This is very strange behaviour and i am not able to identify what is causing this. Do you have any idea what can cause this issue ? @Shay Shmeltzer